# Retrieve paypal subscription data after approval

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

Afternoon

I am a bit of a PayPal integration newbie and having been working on a project where customers use a subscription button to purchase goods. Everything works well however I need to retrieve subscription data after approval for further use. Initially I need the email address so we can send a customised automated email thanking the customer for their purchase but going forward would like the majority of the data so it can be placed in an SQL database.

The onApprove: function(data, actions) seems to be the place to enter code but not overly sure where to start. The subscriptionID seems to be pulled and used within the default code, but when I try and pull another piece of data nothing happens.

`onApprove: function(data, actions) { //alert('You have successfully created subscription ' + data.subscriptionID); alert('Here is the email address ' + data.subscriber.email_address); }`

Is my reference to the email address wrong or does paypal only give you access to the subscriptionID which can then be passed to another PHP page and I can use do a REST API request for the subscription data??

Many thanks chris

Answer (score 2):

`console.log(data)` in the onApprove will show you the data that is available on the client side.

To log information to a server, you should not depend on approval notifications from the client, since they may fail for any number of reasons. Instead, (using the correct clientid) [subscribe to webhooks](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/webhooks/event-names/#subscriptions) related to subscriptions, particularly the PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED event so you receive an update every time a subscription is successfully renewed.

For reconciliation (so you know what payment is for what), you can pass your own arbitrary `custom_id` when the subscription is first created. This will be returned in the webhook.